# Working backwards from Nueral network result

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

As I understand it, Prisma-like applications use convolution neural networks to stylize an image to create output in the style of a set of trained input.

Is it possible to work backwards from the output stylized image, to get back to the original, with these sorts of algorithms, or are they too lossy?

I.E. if I am in possession of the training data, and the output, can I get to the source image?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the original image back.

I'm sure for some pictures you can come up with something that looks more like a photograph again but most of the high frequent information from the original image is lost.